# Call External Web Service Using REST

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-services, ajax

I want to access external web service using ajax call.

I access `http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers` web service in ajax call on site pages. but it is giving me error

> Access Denied

Answer (score 1):

Paste your web service URL directly in browser to check whether it asks for credentials if it is then pass credentials something like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
          username: id,
          password: pass
        },
        success: function(content) { alert('ok'); },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {   
        },
        complete: function() {.. };
     });
})
```

change id and pass as per requirment